# Stored Procedure in MongoDB API: Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Mongo Collection is getting corrupted after executing a stored procedure on Azure Cosmos DB with Mongo API.
Here is the body of the stored procedure:

```js
function bulkImport(docs) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();


    var count = 0;


    if (!docs) throw new Error("The array is undefined or null.");

    var docsLength = docs.length;
    if (docsLength == 0) {
        getContext().getResponse().setBody(0);
    }


    tryCreate(docs[count], callback);


    function tryCreate(doc, callback) {
        var options = {
            disableAutomaticIdGeneration: true
        };

        var isAccepted = collection.createDocument(collectionLink, doc, options, callback);

        if (!isAccepted) getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
    }


    function callback(err, doc, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        count++;

        if (count >= docsLength) {
            getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
        } else {
            tryCreate(docs[count], callback);
        }
    }
}
```

Here executed Stored Procedure directly in Cosmos DB data-explorer.
input:[{ 'type': 'A', 'name':'test' }].

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you set `disableAutomaticIdGeneration` to be `true` and you did not provide `"id"` property in your input `[{ 'type': 'A', 'name':'test' }]`. This will cause exception.

You could set `disableAutomaticIdGeneration` to be `false` or you provide `"id"` property in your input and it works.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I tried by supplying id, it did not work. I tried setting 'disableAutomaticIdGeneration' to false, it did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I heard from Azure support:

triggers, and UDFs are a feature exposed through our SQL API. #CosmosDB’s MongoDB API uses MongoDB programmability surface area – which does not use the concept of sprocs, triggers, UDF’s. Please connect with us at AskCosmosDB@microsoft.com and we will help you.